# Where will we use static syncronization(Java)

Tags: java, static, synchronization

static synchronized method locks in the class object and the synchronized method locks the current instance of an object. I am not able to relate to any real-world examples and cant clearly distinguish the difference between them. So if possible give me some examples that I can relate to concept.

Comment: there is only one class object for all instances, so lock on class will block all callers, lock on instances only callers to the same instance

Comment: So, if there is a lock in instance level, then no other instance can access the class right?, then what is the need of locking it in class level.

Comment: no, if you lock instance - all other instances can be accessed

Comment: So, if i lock in instance level, another instance can access the class while the first instance is working/executing?

Comment: yes, caller can access another instance

Comment: Static synchronized should be avoided because you're creating a bottleneck. So there aren't going to be lots of good real world examples because it's not usually a good thing. Sounds like you're not clear on scope of locking.

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at Java's Thread class. It offers self explanatory examples.

Synchronized static method - single JVM wide id generator

```
private static int threadInitNumber;
private static synchronized int nextThreadNum() {
    return threadInitNumber++;
}
```

Synchronized instance method - lock each thread instance:

```
public synchronized void start() {
  ...
}
```